# PHP How to reverse engineer the day of the year 3212 (YDDD) into 2013-08-01 (YYYY-mm-dd)

Tags: php, date

I have a date in `YDDD` format such 3212 
**I want to convert this date into default date string i.e. 2013-08-01 in PHP** 
Since the first value `Y` is the only character for Year, so I've decided to take the first three characters from the current Year i.e. 201 from 2013 
The following is the code I've written for year

```
<?php
$date = "3212"
$y = substr($date,0,1); // will take out 3 out of year 3212
$ddd = substr($date,1,3); // will take out 212 out of year 3212
$year = substr(date("Y"),0,3) . $y; //well create year "2013"
?>
```

Now How can I use `$year` and `212` to convert it into **2013-08-01** using PHP

**EDIT** 
FYI: My PHP Version is `5.3.6`

Comment: From where you are getting date in `YDDD` format?

Comment: with this how you are going to distinguish 2003 and 2013 so on ?? and what the heck these last 3 D stands for??

Comment: **are you serious ??** date in YDDD format ?? and why is that ?? first , i think you need to look into your date format...lets say you 4122.. so which year is this.. 1994,2004,1884 so on ??

Comment: how does 3 represent an year !!

Comment: @YogeshSuthar client data in text i have to parse it and put it into the database. and this is a standard data so cannot do anything about it. :/

Comment: @zzlalani Change client problem solved. :)

Comment: I just have this to answer you all. http://bavister.org/tools/YDDDcalculator.php

Comment: @YogeshSuthar lol thanks for the advice but i'm stuck now :p

Comment: Back in the days of 201X, when memory was precious, you had throw away as many digits as possible... Wait, what?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$date = "3212";
echo DateTime::createFromFormat("Yz", "201$date")->format("Y-m-d");
// 2013-08-01
```

- [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat)
- See it [running online](https://eval.in/private/961bd08f978f5d)

Comment: This version of answer is better.

Answer (score 8):

```
$yddd = 3212;
preg_match('/^(\d)(\d{3})$/', $yddd, $m);

echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("201{$m[1]}-01-01 00:00:00 +{$m[2]} days"));
```

Comment: Why do we have to regex all teh thingz?

Comment: @Designer Why not? I find that more elegant than a ton of inscrutable `substr`s. :)

Comment: Ha :) That's fair. Why not just `strtotime("201{$yddd[0]}-01-01 +{$yddd[1]}{$yddd[2]}{$yddd[3]} days")` though?

Comment: @Designer Meh, take your pick... There are many ways to skin that cat. :)

Answer (score 6):

If you are running the code on PHP 5.3 or later, you can convert $year and $ddd to a usable date by using date_create_from_format. For example:

```
$date = date_create_from_format("Y-z", "$year-$ddd");
echo date_format($date, "Y-m-d");
```

Comment: Also, note that date_create_from_format is an alias for DateTime::createFromFormat, and neither are available in PHP < 5.3.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Formatted Date (YDDD)
$dateGiven = "3212";

// Generate the year based on the first digit
$year = substr(date("Y"),0,3).substr($dateGiven,0,1);

// Split out the day of the year
$dayOfTheYear = substr($dateGiven,1,3);

// Create a date object from the formatted date
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('z Y',  "{$dayOfTheYear} {$year}");

// Output the date in the desired format
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

[View it online here: https://eval.in/private/69daafa849ee36](https://eval.in/private/69daafa849ee36)